# How can I fade the background image of my scroll panel using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I tried the below code but I am not able to fade the background image residing in the .pane class of my scroll panel.

```
$(".pane").scroll(function() {
  var y = $(".pane").scrollRight();
  if (y > 50) {
    $(".bg").fadeIn("slow");
  } else {
    $(".bg").fadeOut("slow");
  };
});
```

Here is my HTML code for the same
 I am using pane class for containing my background image and driver class contains the div which is to be scrolled. I want that on scroll the background image should fade.

```
<div class="row disp pane bg">
  <h5 class="text">Check Now</h5>
  <h4 class="text1">Popular Clicks</h4>
  <div id="driver" class="dis bord" style="margin-left:1080px;">
    <img src="images/wrogn.jpg" class="image" alt="women">
    <p class="text-muted brand"><strong>WROoGN</strong></p>
    <h5 style="line-height:0px"><strong>&#8377;1,660</strong></h5>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p class="text-muted" style="font-size:11px">&#8377;<del>2,660 </del></p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p class="text-danger" style="font-size:10px">&nbsp;40% OFF
            <p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: you are applying fadeIn to `.bg` which is the same element as `.pane`

Comment: Thanks but .bg is the class that contains the background image and its property. i want that it should fade on scrolling.

Comment: What changes should i make to make it fade?